# How would I reverse a css transition property width?

Tags: html, css

So I want to make a css animation property where the width extends toward the left but it always extends to the right. I am trying to figure how to make the width extend left instead of the default right. How should I approach this problem? JsFiddle below
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPUuL/1/)

 
 Html:`<div></div>`
Css:

```
div
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:130px;
    left:130px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s; 
}

div:hover
{
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: As you have set its position 130 from bottom and also from left, So it always extends to the right as you have fixed its position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust the `left` value as well:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPUuL/2/)

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:130px;
    left:130px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transition:left 2s, width 2s;
}
div:hover {
    left:30px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override your left side in order to extend the width leftward.
You have used `left:130px;` is the starting point of your div. And on `div:hover` you still didn't change the left so it automatically extends to the rightward as you have also sets the `bottom:130px;`

Your default `width:100px;` is change on `div:hover` to `width:200px;` so you need to decrease your left starting position on `div:hover`.  Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/dTc8b/).

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:130px;
    left:130px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transition:left 2s, width 2s;
}
div:hover {
    left:30px;
    width:200px;
}
```