# HTML reverse transition direction

Tags: html, css

Much like this question here ([How would I reverse a css transition property width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694199/how-would-i-reverse-a-css-transition-property-width)) I want to reverse the way my transition goes.

Unfortunately it's not working for me! It might be that my code is a little more complex then that. Can anyone lend me a hand?

JSFiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/cPUuL/4/

CSS:

```
    .Imgpad
{
padding-top:2px;
padding-left:2px;
padding-bottom:3px;
padding-right:2px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

.hidetext {
float:right;
display:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:#CC0000;
font-size:30px;
font-family:"Juice ITC";
}

.Rightbox
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:black;
transition: left 2s, width 2s;
position:absolute;
}

.Rightbox:hover{
width:250px;
}

.Rightbox:hover > .hidetext {
display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div id="Divpos5">
<div class="Rightbox">
    <img class="Imgpad" src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/588/58832_300.jpg" height="96" width="96" alt="Faye">
    <p class="hidetext">Raven Faye<br><font color="#9900CC"></font>~The Sorceress
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks
-Asteria

Comment: Could you explain what's not working.

Comment: I would like it to go to the left, not the right, as on the website I'm building for Tafe I want to have a couple of these on either side of the text

Comment: Well currently it's not actually moving to the left or to the right... Also your html is full of errors.

Comment: Hmm, odd. The JSfiddle moves to the left fine for me

Comment: Not it doesn't move, the width is changed but the position doesn't move to the left.

Comment: Ahh there has been a miscommunication on my part. Sorry, english isn't my first language. I want the width to change left instead of right, while it's start point stays in one area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you were looking for but here's what I did...

http://jsfiddle.net/cPUuL/5/

The css:

```
.Imgpad {
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:2px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-right:2px;
}

.hidetext {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    color:#CC0000;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:"Juice ITC";
    background: #000; 
    height: 96px;
    width: 96px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: left 0.5s, width 0.5s;

}

.Rightbox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:black;
    position: relative;
}

.Rightbox:hover > .hidetext {
    left: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    transition: left 1s, width 1s;
}
```

As you can see the transition speed on the `.Rightbox:hover > .hidetext`; is slower than the one without `:hover`, It means that the reverse transition will change faster than on `.Rightbox:hover > .hidetext`. In other words, the reverse transition is when you move your mouse out of the `Rightbox`.

And the html fixed. You have lots of unclosed tags and the `font` tag that is clearly useless there.

```
<div class="Rightbox">
    <img class="Imgpad" src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/588/58832_300.jpg" height="96" width="96" alt="Faye" />
    <p class="hidetext">Raven Faye<br />~The Sorceress</p>
</div>
```

Here's an updated fiddle that change the `right` property since if you want to make it move to the left, you'll have to change the right corner.

http://jsfiddle.net/cPUuL/6/

The css changed is:

```
.Rightbox:hover > .hidetext {
    right: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    transition: left 1s, width 1s;
}

.hidetext {

    ... 
    right: 0px; /* instead of left: 0px; */
    ...
}
```

I also added a margin to `Rightbox` so we can see the change.

Using this css you can also make a cool transition:

```
.Rightbox,
.Imgpad,
.hidetext {
    transition: left 1s, width 1s;
}

.Rightbox:hover,
.Rightbox:hover .Imgpad,
.Rightbox:hover .hidetext {
    transition: left 0.5s, width 0.5s;
}

.Imgpad {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:2px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-right:2px;
}

.hidetext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 102px;
    bottom: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #CC0000;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:"Juice ITC";
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.Rightbox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:black;
    position: relative;
}

.Rightbox:hover {
    width: 404px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed it slightly to match the speed of my left side ones, but it works perfectly. Thank you thank you thank you <3 <3 <3