# CSS - How to determine the direction of a transition?

Tags: css

I'm using the next CSS rules for a div

```
    transition-property:  width;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
```

The thing is that currently the behavior is that the transition direction is going from right to left.

Is there anyway to make the transition  go the other way around, meaning from left to right? 
Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can you add HTML and probably rest of CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694199/how-would-i-reverse-a-css-transition-property-width

Answer (score 0):

The transition works only for elements that are selected by the query. So if you have this html:

```
<div>sdlfkj</div>
```

And this css (*WRONG*):

```
div{
  width:100px;
}
div:hover{
  width:200px;
  transition: width 2s;
}
```

The transition will work only if you hover the element. **Not** if you unhover the element, because there is no `:unhover`! If you like to have the transition while unhovering the element too, you need to put the transition to the element that will be selected in the unhovered state then.

Use this (*RIGHT*):

```
div{
  width:100px;
  transition: width 2s;
}
div:hover{
  width:200px;
}
```